# How to get Refresh token in FedEx Authorization API OAuth2.0?

Tags: fedex

Im using **fedex api** for Authorization, and cant find any resource for getting refresh token.
Can anybody suggest some solution, it'll be helpful.

*This is the response now I'm getting,*

**URL: /oauth/token**

**Request body:**

grant_type:client_credentials

client_id:784sdsrfere

client_secret:vnjn8741cdsc3e7

scope=openid offline_access

**Response:**

{

"access_token": "eyJhbGciOiJSUzI1NiIsInR5cCI6IkpXVCJ9.eyJzY29wZSI6WyJDWFMtVFAiXSwiUGF5bG9hZCI6eyJjbGllbnRJZGVuB5MQahTTyMPLQnucflB6sc4hk_Gatx3L2Dgs3YkDMV4r3ORiB2EZKOOIfdKRSBVP5PmBEcYYXvG3bTcqe_X6UTgpxdwBNbNHKZL4",

"token_type": "bearer",

"expires_in": 3599,

"scope": "CXS-TP"

}